# RTE plugin in CQ5 using CQ.Util.Build

Tags: aem, rich-text-editor

I need to create a RTE using the CQ.Util.Build (as an extension to what has been done in the "/foundation/social/blog/entryform" JSP).
I am using CQ5.6 and Firefox browser

The final editor needs to have somewhat these features :

[image]

I tried using this code but I still don't see any new features in the editor:

```
{
                "xtype":"richtext",
                "id":"<%= id %>_text",
                "name":"text",
                "enableSourceEdit":true,
                "width":"100%",
                "rtePlugins":{
                        "spellcheck":{"features":"*"},
                        "image":{"features":"* "},
                        "edit":{"features":"* "},
                        "justify":{"features":"* "},
                        "misctools":{"features":"* "},
                        "table":{"features":"* "},
                        "undo":{"features":"* "}}
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue with the properties I've added.

The `"features":"* "` has an extra space everywhere with the `"*"`. After removing it, it is working fine